# Como mudar a base de um branch?

Tags: git

Tenho um branch derivado da `master`, `development`, que nunca volta à `master`. Todos os branchs de `features` são derivados de `development`, mas após testados e validados, são combinados tanto com a `development` quando com a `master`. Não posso combinar diretamente a `development` com a `master` porque tenho `features` lá que ainda não devem ser mescladas com a `master`.

Gostaria de saber se há algum meio de mudar o branch base de uma `feature` sem ocasionar conflitos nos arquivos que não foram alterados apenas nessa `feature`.

Hoje posso fazer o `git cherry-pick <commit>` mas acredito que em uma árvore com muitos commits seja um tanto quanto trabalhoso.

O desenho dos fluxos das minhas `branchs` é mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
                                   .-[feature1]---o---o---o-.
                                  /                          \
                                 /   .-[feature2]---o-.       \
                                /   /                  \       \
             .-[development]---´---´--------------------+-------+
            /                                            \       \
[master]---´----------------------------------------------+-------+---...

o - commits                    + - merge
```

No desenho acima, hoje, o que seria o `merge` estou fazendo como `cherry-pick`.

Comment: Acho que não chega a ser uma resposta ideal, mas `git cherry-pick A^..B` faz o cherry-pick de todos os commits entre A a B (incluindo os próprios commits A e B)

Comment: @hkotsubo mas o problema é que vai pegar de todos os `branchs` que tenham `commit` naquele período, não?

Comment: Se for da forma que está na figura, acho que não. Se todos os commits entre A e B pertencem ao branch feature1, só vai pegar esses.

Comment: @hkotsubo então, mas não é o caso, porque o desenvolvimento da `feature1` e `feature2` ocorrem em paralelo. Me ocorreu agora que talvez eu possa dar `squash` no `pull request` ao colocar em `development` e depois fazer o `cherry-pick` apenas do `merge`. Não sei se dá pra fazer isso

Comment: É, também não sei. Eu costumo usar o git de um jeito mais "básico" (branch -> push -> pull request), de vez em quando eu faço um cherry-pick ou rebase aqui e ali, mas é só. Não sou de fazer muitos "malabarismos", e muito menos de sugerir que os outros o façam. Desculpe não poder ajudar mais...

Comment: Por favor, reformula sua pergunta porque não consigo entender o que você quer fazer exatamente. Idealmente, com um diagrama antes e depois.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [rebase com a opção `--onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/pt_BR#git-rebase---ontoltnova-basegt). Os nomes das branches abaixo são só exemplos.

```sh
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase --onto base-nova base-antiga feature-branch
```

Se as duas bases forem incompatíveis, ou os commits da feature-branch forem dependentes da base antiga, vão existir conflitos de merge. Como o rebase pode ser perigoso, aconselho deixar tudo no remoto antes das alterações para poder voltar se precisar. E pra voltar, é só fazer um hard reset.

```sh
git rebase --abort # se for necessário
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/feature-branch # ou qualquer outra branch que você esteja
```